# Convert date and time to only year in php

Tags: php, drupal

I have a variable is which the value coming is Date along with time in php. How do I convert it into a variable to get only the year? I do not need automatic updation but the format change is needed. Normal answers are giving it about date but my variable is containing time as well.

```
The format coming by now is 2017-12-11 4:06:37 and i need only 2017
```

Comment: If you want a Drupal specific answer, you should ask a more Drupal specific question. As you are using Drupal, you probably don't need to use PHP and can do it in the interface somewhere, but that depends on where this date is being output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like this:

```
<?php echo date('Y',strtotime('now'));?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can you simple DateTime function and date_formate() function for displaying separate year, month and date.

For that you have to first convert in Object of your current Date time string by using :

```
$date = new \DateTime('2017-12-11 4:06:37');
```

And then you can use date format function by using below code:

```
echo date_format($date, "Y"); //for Display Year
echo date_format($date, "m"); //for Display Month
echo date_format($date, "d"); //for Display Date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can code like this (working perfectly):

```
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2009-02-15 15:16:17');
echo "Format: $format; " . $date->format('Y') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Himanshu Upadhyay, this is correct and the easiest way.

```
<?php 
  echo date('Y',strtotime('now'));
?>
```

But i would recommend you to read this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). You should really do actually!

Answer (score 0):

By using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class

```
$date = new \DateTime('2017-12-11 4:06:37');
echo $date->format('Y');
```